# create a distance matrix in R (without using dist())

Tags: r, matrix, distance

I need to create a distance matrix from a matrix, which returns the distance between columns.

**I KNOW** that it exists a function called dist() but I cannot use it because I will use not common distance functions.

I was thinking about using apply, but I don't know how to write it.

The loop I have created is:

```
 dista <- function(A,distance){
  dist_matrix=matrix(0,dim(A)[2],dim(A)[2])
  for (i in 1:(dim(A)[2]-1)){
    for(j in (i+1):(dim(A)[2])){
      if(distance=='cosine') dist_matrix[j,i]<- (1-sum(A[,i]*A[,j]))/(sqrt(sum(A[,i]^2))+sqrt(sum(A[,j]^2)))
    }
  }
  dist_matrix
}
```

Comment: Can you post an example of your columns of data and your expected output? Perhaps even the loop code you wrote that is slow?

Comment: More details would help.

Comment: I've just wrote the loop, my matrix is 129569rows x 60columns

Comment: how about http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/lsa/docs/cosine ? (I just googled "r pairwise cosine distance')

Comment: Yes! this helps thanks but how can I write it without a loop?

Comment: I think that function constructs the whole distance matrix for you.  Have you tried it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have some data frame like this:

```
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10, 5, 1), y = rnorm(10))
```

You can use apply as follows:

```
apply(df, 1, dist)
```

To use a customer distance function, you can replace the call to `dist` above with:

```
apply(df, 1, my_own_dist)
```

Of course, this loops through each row of data, and will still be slower than a matrix based computation. Knowing what your distance function actually does might help folks get you an even more efficient way to approach the problem.

EDIT based on comment below....

If you are trying to compute pair-wise distance between every pair of columns in your original matrix A, you can try something like this:

```
apply(combn(1:ncol(A), 2), 2, function(x) my_dist_function(A[, x]))
```

First generate all unique column pairs, and run through them one at a time

Comment: Thanks, but I use the cosine distance so, how can I write it?

Comment: If you are trying to compute pair-wise distance between every pair of columns in your original matrix A, you can try something like this: `apply(combn(1:ncol(A), 2), 2, function(x) my_dist_function(A[, x]))`. First generate all unique column pairs, and run through them one at a time.

Comment: Thank you, that is just what I need